# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val' num = my_list.val + new_sum

Tags: python, error-handling, attributeerror

I'm trying to learn python but I'm having some trouble. I need to use two linked lists and create a new one with their sums, I can assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself, but I'm getting the error

```
   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'
    num = my_list.val + new_sum
Line 80 in addTwoNumbers (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().addTwoNumbers(param_1, param_2)
Line 121 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 132 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I don't understand why would my_list be an int and not have a val if I initialized it as I did.
This is the code that generates the error:

```
    # Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution: 
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
                    my_list = ListNode(0)
                    my_list.next = 0
                    ptr = my_list
                    def countSize(lst: Optional[ListNode]) -> int:
                        r = 0
                        while lst:
                            r += 1
                            lst = lst.next
                        return r
                    num1 = countSize(l1)
                    num2 = countSize(l2)
                    if num1 > num2:
                        i = 0
                        while l1:
                            if i > num2:
                                new_sum = l1.val
                                num = my_list.val + new_sum
                                if num > 9:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum - 10
                                    my_list.next.val = 1
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l1 = l1.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum
                                    my_list.next = 0
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l1 = l1.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                            else:
                                new_sum = l1.val + l2.val
                                num = my_list.val + new_sum
                                if num > 9:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum - 10
                                    my_list.next.val = 1
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l1 = l1.next
                                    l2 = l2.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum
                                    my_list.next = 0
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l1 = l1.next
                                    l2 = l2.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                    else:
                        i = 0
                        while l2:
                            if i > num1:
                                new_sum = l2.val
                                num = my_list.val + new_sum
                                if num > 9:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum - 10
                                    my_list.next.val = 1
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l2 = l2.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum
                                    my_list.next = 0
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l2 = l2.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                            else:
                                new_sum = l1.val + l2.val
                                num = my_list.val + new_sum
                                if num > 9:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum - 10
                                    my_list.next.val = 1
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l1 = l1.next
                                    l2 = l2.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    my_list.val = my_list.val + new_sum
                                    my_list.next = 0
                                    my_list = my_list.next
                                    l1 = l1.next
                                    l2 = l2.next
                                    i += 1
                                    continue
                    return ptr
```

Comment: The value you're returning is an int, not a ListNode.   Is that what you intended?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right error traceback. Can you update your question with the full error traceback?

Comment: @quamrana updated all the details

Comment: @MarkLavin yes I want to check that the sum of the value inside the node and the new_sum is less than 10

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of lines like this: `my_list = my_list.next`.

The very first time a line like this runs, `my_list` becomes an `int` and the next time you hit `my_list.val` you will get the error.

Comment: how do I fix this?

Comment: Well, that depends. Why do you have lines like: `my_list.next = 0`? You seem to be deliberately setting the `next` reference to an `int`. What does that mean? Did you mean something else?

Comment: @quarama I just don't understand how memory works in python and how to initialize the next node/create it

Comment: The `next` node is automatically initialised to `None`, But if you just omit lines like `my_list.next = 0`, then where there is a `my_list = my_list.next`, then `my_list` becomes `None` and you have the same problem. You should update your question with a minimal example so that I can just paste the whole lot into a python file and try it myself.